# Simplest Way To Create Custom Builds of the Same App, Different Assets

Tags: iphone, xcode, build

I'm building an iPhone app that will be branded for several different companies. Each company will get their own app. The code base is the same. Really, the only thing that will be different between them are the app name, app icon, default image, and a few images used inside the app. Is there a best practice to automate this? I am pursuing scripting everything and have some preliminary scripts somewhat working, but it occurred to me there may be a simpler way with Xcode 4.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Nice question, though i know one way but i am sure you would want something really optimal. So i will mark it for later viewing. Hopefully we get a cool answer.

Comment: @Matt Long u r helping lots of dev by cimgf.com.thanku.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a new workspace and add a new project for every own app. You **won't** need to create all classes for every project. Just create a "core" project with your code base and add his files **by reference** to the custom projects.

Answer (score 0):

i have same scenario , in which we maintain a global-config File which contain all UI Elements like NavBar , Buttons everything , as we have same layout for all clients , so we maintain a same layout with different color Theme the client choose,.

so for distribution , we change the settings in global file , then add the Client Provision  ,& will send for review.

Hope this Helps

Comment: Sounds like a very manual process. I'm wanting to automate it as much as possible. When you say "global-config file", what are you referring to? What kind of file is it?